# iOS PushKit error callback

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

I am developing a VoIP app which uses `PushKit` to wake up a device while an incoming call is going to ring.

My problem is that **`PushKit` does not handle the case when push token cannot be created e.g.:**

- user disables push notifications
- Apple reviewers testing app on simulator which does not support push notifications (yes - my case).

There is the only callback `didUpdatePushCredentials` which is called when a push token from ANPs successfully comes. I am showing a loading animation while getting this push token and sending it to my server. But I need the callback which tells: "hey, something went wrong while registering to APNs" to stop loading animation and show an error to the user.

Did the Apple forget to implement failure callback or have I implement delayed code block to check if an app did already get push token?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate - didInvalidatePushTokenFor: PKPushType)
Notifies the delegate that a push token has been invalidated.

Comment: @Jordan thanks for the comment but you did not understand the problem. `didInvalidatePushTokenFor : This method is invoked if a previously provided push token is no longer valid for use.`. There is no any callback which is called when providing new push token fails.

Comment: Looks like you may have to come up with your own custom code to handle it. I agree it's strange Apple didn't provide a built-in method for handling errors such as this.